# Any other way to count group records in crystal reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to count the total no of records found under a group and according to that i need to assign reduction percentages. 
In Detail,

- if a user got less than 3 products he ll get 10%
- if a user got 4-10 products he ll get 15%
- if he got 10-20 products he ll get 20% as deduction

For example consider the following as a crystal report: 
**User 1** 
**Product        Deduction**
Apple              15 % 
Orange           15 % 
Lemon            15 % 
Strawberry      15 % 
Grapes           15 % 
Here i made a count of records in this group using running total and worte a formula. Depends on the count its ll make the deductions
But the problem in getting is, I'm getting the following output...
**User 1** 
**Product        Deduction**
Apple              10 %    // *Since count is 1*
Orange           10 %    // *Since count is 2*
Lemon            10 %    // *Since count is 3*
Strawberry      15 %    // *Since count is 4*
Grapes           15 %    // *Since count is 5*
I wanna make all products deduction as 15 % if the total no of records are 4-15. Here the total no of products is 5 its in the range of 4-15 so all the product should have the deduction as 15 %.
Please help me out to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a running-total field (RT) for a simple count; use a summary field instead.  The summary field can be used in the group's header and footer (a RT can only be used in the footer).

Select a field (preferably a unique field), then select Insert | Summary Field...  Choose Count or Distinct Count from the picklist.

You can use this summary in a formula as well:

```
//{@discount}
//Assumes there is a group on {table.fruit_name}):
SELECT Count({table.key_field}, {table.fruit_name})
CASE 1 to 3: .1
CASE 4 to 5: .15
DEFAULT: 0
```

Comment: Thx a lot ! It works very fine and me too figured it out, and this is the right answer... I have furthur doubt in this report :(

Comment: I wrote a formula "final_amt", this is generated after deducting the deduction% from the gross amount. I get final_amt for all the fruits. How I can sum all those final_amt? since formula cant be summarized is there any other way to sum it??

Comment: Create a formula field for each fruit that segments the amount.  For example: `If {table.fruit_type}='Apple' Then {table.amount}`...  Then add a summarized field for each formula field.  Finally, create another set of formula fields (one for each fruit) that calculates the difference between the summary and the discount.